# Pass variables from one test case to another in Robot framework (Not using global variable)

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, automation, robotframework

Lets say I have a test-suite with two test cases. I just want to pass the variable used in one test case to the other one.

Yes, I know we can use `Set Global Variable` to make it as global variable and use it. I just want know, Is there any other way that we can achieve this?

If there is a way, then how it differs from `Set Global Variable`?

Comment: Have you had a look at [Set Suite Variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Suite%20Variable) which scopes the variable to those test cases within the running Suite.

Comment: I'm new to this robot framework. Not heard ```Set Suite Variable``` before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only built-in choice for setting a variable in one test and making it available in another is to use either [Set Global Variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Global%20Variable) or [Set Suite Variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Suite%20Variable).

The difference between the two is that setting a suite variable limits the visibility to tests in the current file. Setting a global variable makes the variable visible to all tests in all files.